# Plot lineshape every 5th point on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot using ggplot where several lines are ploted. The x-axis goes from `1:100`.

I would also like to include line shapes for each line but I would not like to display them for each point on the x-axis. Instead I want to plot them every 5th point so `seq(1,100,5)`

I cannot find the appropriate command for this but I assume it exists.
Can someone help?

Comment: This seems to be quite broad. Could you explain more clearly what kind lines you want to plot? Vertical lines at every 5th point? You could use `geom_vline` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean? You could add an extra column to your `data.frame` and use `geom_point()` to plot it with whatever shape you like. Just repeat for each line you are plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
pd <- data.frame(x = c(1:100), y = rnorm(100))
pd$pt <- pd$y
pd$pt[-seq(1, 100, 5)] <- NA

ggplot(pd, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = pt))
```